# If $C \subset X \subset \mathbb P^n$ is a canonical smooth hyperplane section, then $n=g(C)$.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I'm studying Theorem 3.3 of Miles Reid's [*Chapters on Algebraic surfaces*](http://arxiv.org/pdf/alg-geom/9602006v1.pdf) (page 66) and I can't understand the beginning of the second part of the proof. That is: if $X \subset \mathbb P^n$ is a smooth projective complex surface (I also assume that the inclusion is nondegenerate, even if Reid doesn't) and $C \subset X$ is a smooth hyperplane section which is a canonical curve, then - as written in the proof - $n=g=g(C)$, the genus of $C$.

How can I argue? Detailed and even *pedantic* answers are welcome!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $H$ is the hyperplane of $\mathbb{P}^n$ s.t. $C=X\cap H$, then $C\subset H\cong \mathbb{P}^{n-1}$ is canonical implies that $n-1=g(C)-1$, hence $n=g(C)$.

Comment: This makes sense; I probably misunderstood the notion of "canonical hyperplane section". I shall review the argument again; thanks!

Comment: Dear @FrancescoGenovese, maybe I made a same mistake with you: I thought $C$ is a canonical divisor at first.