# Understanding the last part of M. Reid's proof of "If $X \subset \mathbb P^n$ has a canonical hyperplane section then $X$ is a K3".

Tags: algebraic-geometry

This question is related to [this other one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/464978/if-c-subset-x-subset-mathbb-pn-is-a-canonical-smooth-hyperplane-section-t). I'm studying Theorem 3.3 on Miles Reid's [*Chapters on Algebraic Surfaces*](http://arxiv.org/pdf/alg-geom/9602006v1.pdf) (page 66) and I have problems understanding the last paragraph. I quote:

> [...] Thus $K_X$ is linearly equivalent to an effective divisor $D \geq 0$.
>   But the adjunction formula $K_C = (K_X +C)_{|C}$ together with the
>   assumption $K_C = C_{|C}$ implies that $D \cap C = \emptyset$, so that
>   $D=0$. Thus $K_X = 0$.

For the sake of clarity, I recall that $C$ is assumed to be a hyperplane section of $X$ which is a canonical curve.

I don't have a clue to explain the above argument (save for the very first claim: $K_X \sim D$)!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just compute, using the adjunction formula, and the assumptions that $K_X = D$ and $K_C = C_{|C}$:
We have $$D_{|C} = (K_X)_{|C} = K_C - C_{|C} = 0,$$
the first and last equality holding by assumption, and the middle equality holding by adjunction.

Since $D_{|C} = 0$, we have that $D\cdot C = \deg(D_{|C}) = 0,$ and so $D$ has trivial intersection with $C$.

To deduce from this that $D = 0$ you must be using some additional fact about $C$ that you haven't stated in your post (since in general in a surface you can have two effective curves with empty intersection).

Added: The key point is the fact that you edited in to your post: $C$ is a hyperplane section!  Thus if $D \cap C = \emptyset,$ then $D$ must itself vanish.  (A non-empty effective curve will have a non-empty intersection with any hyperplane (or with any non-empty hypersurface) by the basic properties of intersection theory in $\mathbb P^n$.)

Comment: $C$ is assumed to be a canonical hyperplane section. That is, a hyperplane section of $X$ which is a canonical curve. Does it help?

Comment: @FrancescoGenovese: Dear Francesco, The key point is that $C$ is a hyperplane section.  (I edited my answer to take this into account.) Regards,